# After changing job criteria I still see and receive only jobs related to the old criterias

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I was using the frontend and ios criterias before (javascipt, html/css, node.js, swift, obj-c and so on).

Recently I've tried to search for jobs in completely different field – game developemnt and Unreal Engine.

But after changing the criterias and even when I'm explicitly search for "Unreal Engine" I still get only frontend or ios jobs. The same for the alert emails – they are still about frontend positions.

[image: the example of what I get]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want a search for [`"unreal engine"`](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&q=%22unreal+engine%22). Searching for `unreal engine` (no quotes) will search for listings that contain:

- "unreal engine" (together) - these should get weighted toward the top of the results
- unreal and engine (in any part of the listing) - these are given additional weight but not enough to send them to the top of the results
- unreal or engine (in any part of the listing)

I can't see any job alerts associated with the account you posted with. Is it possible you have more than one account? What email address were the job alerts sent to; you can send it to me at dward@stackoverflow.com and I'll take a look.

Comment: Well, with quotes it's definitely better, still not clear why it was Frontend-related when searching without quotes. Probably, it's remembered my previous preferences? But I have changed "Match Preferences" anyway...

About alerts – I have removed it since it send me Frontend jobs... Last time (02-Aug) it sent me 2 frontend jobs.